404 NOT FOUND error when calling endpoint with required claim
I have the following setup:
var services = builder.Services;
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme)
  .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);
services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
  .SetDefaultPolicy(new([new DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement()], 
                    [IdentityConstants.BearerScheme]));
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
  .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

AppUser:
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
  public string? Locale { get; set; }
  public bool? IsAdmin { get; set; }
}

AppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory:
public class AppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory
  : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser>
{
  public AppUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
    UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
    IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
    : base(userManager, optionsAccessor) { }
  protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(AppUser user)
  {
    var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
    if (user.Locale is not null)
    {
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim("locale", user.Locale));
    }
    if (user.IsAdmin == true) //IsAdmin is bool?
    {
      identity.AddClaim(new Claim("is_admin", "is_admin"));
    }
    return identity;
  }
}

Endpoint causing error:
app.MapGet("/admin/page", () => Results.Ok("admin page"))
  .RequireAuthorization(config => config.RequireClaim("is_admin"));

When I call this endpoint, I get 404 Not Found error. I checked that I have required is_admin claim:
app.MapGet("/claims", async (SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, HttpContext http) =>
{
  var user = await signInManager.UserManager.GetUserAsync(http.User);
  if (user is null)
  {
    return Results.BadRequest("User not found");
  }
  var principal = await signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
  return Results.Ok(principal.Claims);
})
  .RequireAuthorization();

However, for some reason I get 404 error.

The problem was that RequireAuthorization should have add Identity Schema:
app.MapGet("/admin/page", () => Results.Ok("admin page"))
  .RequireAuthorization(config =>
  {
    config.AddAuthenticationSchemes(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);
    config.RequireClaim("is_admin"));
  });


New ChatGPT 4-o didn't help...
